# License of content in patent

Tags: copyright, graphics, license, patents

What's the license of content in a patent?

I'd like to refer to existing techniques and show obtained results by including a figure which is obtained from a patent. Am I allowed to do that?

For example I'd like to include a picture from the patent [Producing engraving-style halftone images](https://www.google.com/patents/US7126723) in a journal entry I am writing.

Comment: Some guidance in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_on_the_content_of_patents_and_in_the_context_of_patent_prosecution